# Getting a part of string in tcl

Tags: linux, tcl

I'm trying to split the following string : Groups/Group#1.rpt to get only the word Group#1.rpt using tcl ; I did the following but the output was empty :

```
set verifyFile "Groups/Group#1.rpt" 
set verify_file_name [echo $verifyFile |cut -d "/" -f 2]
```

Comment: Please try to use pure Tcl when possible instead of doing shell commands.   All the builtin commands are here:  https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/contents.html

The `echo` command is not builtin Tcl, but your particular Tcl interpreter allows it and other shell commands.   Calling `echo` prints to stdout, it does not return a value.   The pipe operator after `echo` is probably piping to a subshell that does the `cut` and then exits the subshell.   Using just pure Tcl, like the `split` or `file tail` commands will do what you expect.

Comment: @ChrisHeithoff We prefer to use https://www.tcl-lang.org/ for URLs these days. Same content, same servers, just different DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for a specific built-in: [`file tail`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M38)!

```
set verify_file_name [file tail $verifyFile]
```

Don't use string manipulation directly for this; there are some complex nuances on different platforms. This command handles all the tricky edge cases for you.

Answer (score 2):

Donal's `file tail` answer is perfect for removing the directories from a file path.

If you have a "CSV" string using slash as the delimiter, you can use `split` and `lindex`

```
set verify_file_name [lindex [split $verifyFile /] end]
```